# Why this C program to find the first unique character in a string is too slow?

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C. So, I'm trying to learn through leetcode.

https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/

This is the question

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

Examples:

s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode",
return 2.

And this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int firstUniqChar(char* s) {
  int c = 0;
  int freq[26] = {0};

  while (s[c] != '\0') {
    if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z') {
      freq[s[c] - 'a']++;
    }
    c++;
  }

  int firstChar = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    if (freq[s[i] - 'a'] == 1) {
      firstChar = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return firstChar;
}
```

I can't prove that my code is correct since it said Time limit exceeded. So, I'm guessing my program is too slow. Not sure where did I do it wrong?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is change `i < strlen(s)` to `s[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: Also, make sure to test if `(s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z')` in your second loop, otherwise you might get an out of bounds memory access on your array.

Comment: Your first loop "accidentally" determines the length of `s`, so you get that for free. But then you pointlessly compute the length of `s` over and over later in the code. If you care about performance at all, don't compute the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is accidentally O(n^2) because `strlen(s)` takes O(n) time, and is executed on each iteration of the second loop. As in the first loop, you can iterate until you find a `\0` character:

```
for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

On correctness: your first loop only counts characters if they are in the range `a-z` but your second loop doesn't. That means either that the checks are redundant in the first loop, or the second loop is wrong (because it will access `freq` out of range if there's a character that's not in the range `a-z` in `s`).

Comment: The code is accidentally O(n^3): while loop, for loop, and strlen

Comment: @GabrieleB-David No, O(n + n^2) = O(n^2).

Comment: @GabrieleB-David I don't see it: the while loop and for loop are separate, and the while is O(n) and the for loop O(n^2).

Comment: @GabrieleB-David the `for` and `strlen` are outside of the `while`.

Comment: The checks in the first loop are redundant: "*You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.*"

Comment: @Siguza, Rusty, Paul You guys are right. Please excuse the error, jumped too quickly on that